# How can I recall shell history?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive

I'm learning the hadoop technology stack and Linux at the same time.  I am at hive and started creating an external table.

```
hive> CREATE ETERNAL TABLE users (
      >user_id INT,
      >//and so on
```

Notice the type-o: ETERNAL = *EXTERNAL.  Is there a way to recall the history of all the stuff I typed into the shell?  Then I can fix the type-o and re-run the command.  I tried up arrow, but that only gives me one line.

Comment: That looks like SQL, so you're not in the shell (not in _the_ shell). You should find out what program you're in and read the docs, but since up-arrow doesn't work chances are you're out of luck.

Comment: The history function is something implemented by the shell itself. So you have to check the documentation of the shell you use. Bash writes a history file, an sql client stores history too, no idea how. You did try using the arrow up key to browser the latest history?

Comment: Yes, arrow up did not work.  The program I'm running is `hive`.  Since you guys are telling me that the program is important I'll update the tags.

Comment: If Hive doesn't have readline support or its equivalent there's no history.

Comment: Going off of what you just said Dave then this isn't possible: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the history of all the stuff that you did on the shell type in 'history' in the terminal:
$ history

Output looks like as below in the attached image file.

[image: Output for history command]

And to search for a particular command in the history file you can use the following commands:

$ history | grep command-name

$ history | egrep -i 'scp|ssh|ftp'

Comment: +1 because I can see the command I typed using `history`.  However, this doesn't allow me to edit and re-run the command.  Since this is the best answer I've seen I'm going to mark it.